# How to trim a value by a particular length and then apply lookUp in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, lookup, aggregation, mongodb-charts

The main issue i'm facing is doing multi document joins. For example, when I try and run a query on orders by customer I can't find an easy way to join orders to customers on a customer id because in the orders object the customer id has _user$ appended to the beginning of the user ID and I don't know how to truncate that in an aggregation pipeline.

eg; In the order object, the customer is defined as _p_customer:"_User$8qXjk40eOd"
But in the user table the _id is just 8qXjk40eOd and therfore the default lookup function in charts cannot match the two.

Note: I'm using parse server and it stores pointers in the above mentioned way.

[This is how the data is being stored in the mongoDB order collection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOte5.png)

customer field in the above image is the pointer to the _User collection

[This is how the data is stored in the mongoDB _User collection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAmQ1.png)

My requirement is to write mongo query that find all users and their related orders count. I'm not able to do that because I don't how to remove _User$ from the order row and join it the _User via _id.

Comment: please provide sample data and your expected output data

Comment: Please see the sample data. Thanks @mohammadNaimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before lookup in aggregate `substr` the field you want to use in `$lookup`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
   $addFields :{
       nUser : { $substr: [ "$_p_customer", 6, -1 ] } // _User$ has 6 characters
   }
},
{
   $lookup :{
       from:"usersCollection",
       localField:"nUser",
       foreignField : "_id",
       as : "UserObject"
   }
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad Naimi .. This worked for me and passed the data to the mongo charts as well.